# How to list last 10 files in all the subdirectories in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I have a directory and there a multiple sub directories under that, i want to display the last 10 files recursively from all the subdirectories or if i can mention some date parameters to list also will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Save the name of all directories.

```
  ls -R $PWD/* | grep ./ > allDirectories
```

The next line show 10 files of each directory (only if the directory don't have spaces in their name). You can add more options to the ls command (i.e sort by time using -c)

```
for directory in $(cat allDirectories); do echo '\n\n\n'$directory; ls $directory[1,-2] | head -n 10; done 2>> /dev/null
```